# como hacer una conexion v-link con vue.js + rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

deseo hacer una conexion a otra vista y utilizar los parametros de la primera vista en el

> landig page: video_populares.vue

con vue.js + rails, pero estoy confundido por los ejemplos que encuentro no utilizan para metros de una API, estare agradecido si me pueden ayudar, este es el codigo:

popular_vue.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Popular from './popular.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('popular'))
  const popular = new Vue(Popular).$mount('popular')
  // console.log(app)
})
```

popular.vue :

template con llamado del servicio http con axios e insertados en el template son nombre de video y la imagen

```
<div v-for="nota in notas_p">
      <div class="col-sm-3 post post-6">
        <div class=" m0 inner">
          <div class=" m0 featured_img">
            <a href="#"><img v-bind:src="nota.image_url" alt=""></a>
          </div>
          <div class=" m0 post_contents">
            <div class="m0 category sports">
            </div>
            <h3 class="post_title">
                    <a href="#">{{nota.name}}</a>
                  </h3>
            <ul class="post_meta nav nav-pills">
              <li></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    notas_p: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.notas_p = response.data
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

segunda vista video_populares_vue.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Video_populares from './video_populares.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('video_populares'))
  const video_populares = new Vue(Video_populares).$mount('video_populares')
})
```

video_populares.vue :

en esta vista se imprimiran los datos de la vista anterior cuando se haga la trasicion.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 post interview">
  <div class="row m0 featured_img">

    <div class="video">
      <iframe width="640" height="360" src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    notas_p: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.notas_p = response.data
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

routas en rails:

```
  root 'pages#index'
  get 'pages/index'

  get 'programs/index'
  get 'programs/show'
```

Comment: Hola Julio, te serviría hacer un componente y enviarle los datos al componente para su visualización? o querés redirigir al usuario a otra pagina donde va a estar dicha visualización?

Comment: me serviria la de redirigir al usuario a otra vista ya que tengo creado dos vistas  "video_populares.vue" y "video_programas.vue" con la ruta "programs/index" y "programs/show"

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo como se puede hacer el cambio, les dejo un ejemplo en caso de que alquien tenga dudas como yo tuve:

en route.rb:

```
  get 'index' => 'pages#index'
  get 'regalos' => 'regalo#index'
  get 'acerca' => 'acerca#index'
```

y en la vista navbar.vue:

```
      <ul>
        <li><a v-bind:href="'/index'">Index</a></li>
        <li><a v-bind:href="'/regalos'">Regalos</a></li>
        <li><a v-bind:href="'/acerca'">Acerca de</a></li>
     </ul>
```

y para pasar con un parametro en especifico se hace de esta forma:

route.rb:

```
get 'programas/:Pslug/videos/:Vslug' => "programs#index"
```

index.vue:

```
  <div v-for="video in videos_p">
      <h3 class="post_title">
        <a v-bind:href="'/programas/' + video.program.slug + '/videos/' + video.slug">{{video.name}}</a>
       </h3>
</div>
```